# How to convert relative import to absolute in angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, import

How to convert relative import to absolute import in angular 6?

For example

make `environments/environment` instead of

```
 ../../../../environments/environment
```

Comment: In typescript/javascript land, 'absolute' name in reality means "is published on npm under exactly that name". Trying to circumvent this is not worth the trouble.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually for TypeScript, not necessarily Angular. Here is an example of what you need to add to your `tsconfig.json` file in the root of your project:

```js
{
  // Other TS options here
  "compilerOptions": {
    // more stuff is usually here
    "paths": {
      "@constants/*": ["./app/constants/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./app/components/*"],
      "@directives/*": ["./app/directives/*"],
      "@env/*": ["./environments/*"],
      "@models/*": ["./app/models/*"],
      "@services/*": ["./app/services/*"],
      "@states/*": ["./app/state-management/*"]
    }
  },
  // ...other stuff can be here too
}
```

Then, you will be able to do this within your specific files/components:

```js
import { LoggerService } from '@services/logger/logger.service';
```

Comment: Also, you should add ""baseUrl": "src","

Comment: @MaxKarpovets => That is part of the reason why I did the comments around it to let the OP choose what else needs to be there.

Comment: can an absolute path be used? for example `"C:/aaaa/app/constants/*"` instead of `"./app/constants/*"`

Comment: @ps0604 => I am not sure. Everything I have ever done has been relative imports, so you would have to test it. Sorry that I can't help more than that.

Comment: @th3n3wguy I tried an absolute path and it worked. That way I can share a single directory with two projects.

Comment: That's awesome @ps0604! Good to know you found a way. Congrats!